# Asp.net MVC Layout - Routing Issue With Areas

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I've got an issue with MVC routing(or at least I think it's mvc routing :) )...

here's details of my work flow

In my project i have to create separate user wise login.this is fully customize login section.
so what i did was append my menu bar html in by calling a ajax function ,
$(document).ready(function ()) of that layout page.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divProcessing").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UICustomize", "Home")',
            data: {
            },
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                if (data != '')
                {
                    $('#sidemenulist').append(data);
                    $("#divProcessing").hide();
                }
                else {
                    location.href = "/Home/Login";
                }

            }
        });
 });
```

**"UICustomize", "Home"**

[image]

Now UI changed dynamically user wise.so up-to this part there is no issue.

After that i have to use Area in asp.net mvc for particular modules wise.
then i'm getting issue.
In this area , i cannot use my layout ajax function because my path getting changed.

[image]
'/ClientManagement/Home/UICustomize'
[image]

i want to redirect that path to Home/UICustomize only.
how can that be done?

here's the route:
**RouteConfig**

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

**Area**

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "ClientManagement_default",
            "ClientManagement/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );

    }
```

Comment: If you do not want the area method, then set it to `null` - `@Url.Action("UICustomize", "Home", new { area = "" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can i set it here? 
this is my ajax call url -- url: '@Url.Action("UICustomize", "Home")'
in area this one changed automatically to url: '/ClientManagement/Home/UICustomize',

Comment: Read my comment - add the `new { area = "" }` which will then generate `/Home/UICustomize`. But why are you using ajax for this instead of using `@Html.Action()` to call a child action that generates your menu/sidebar?

Comment: And the fact you have `location.href = "/Home/Login";` in your scripts suggests other design problems with your code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ,ohh its working.. @Url.Action("UICustomize", "Home", new { area = "" })
thanks buddy.. :)
Can you please explain this if it is possible.i didn't understand what you said to me.
"But why are you using ajax for this instead of using @Html.Action() to call a child action that generates your menu/sidebar?"

Comment: So you user makes a request to render a page, but instead of returning all the html, you return only part of it - _sorry, browser, I forgot to send you all the data, so you have to wait a bit longer and make another connection back to the server to get the rest of the html and then add it_. You can just use `@Html.Action()` in your layout to call a `[ChildActionOnly]` method that returns a partial of your menu so its all generated in the one request.

Comment: ah thats a really good idea.right now i'm using this after page load -> send seperate ajax request to load side menu.but with your way(@Html.Action()) i can do it in one request? please share if you have any example url to do this in layout page.
and thanks for you support @stephen..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160574/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tdm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Url.Action()` will default to using the current area which is why its generating a url with the name of your area. To remove it, use

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UICustomize", "Home", new { area = "" })',
    ....
```

which in your case will generate `/Home/UICustomize` instead of `/ClientManagement/Home/UICustomize`.

However you should not be rendering your side bar using ajax. Instead, decorate you `UICustomize()` method with a `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute (so it cannot be navigated to by the user), and in your layout, use

```
@Html.Action("UICustomize", "Home", new { area = "" })
```

or

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("UICustomize", "Home", new { area = "" }); }
```

to render the partial view of your sidebar menu.